# import de.tavendo.autobahn.Wamp cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, android, autobahnws

I want to make android chat app. I'm using autobahn ws. and have 3 libraries. I added all libraries. But when i use this line 
"import de.tavendo.autobahn.Wamp;"
 i get the following error. 
Cannot resolve symbol 'Wamp' how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Where did you add the libraries?

Comment: in libs folder. My libraries are working. I think have an other problem?

Comment: Is your libs folder part of your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your version `de.tavendo.autobahn`, `Wamp` class is available from version 5.1 and later. Best solution is create `jar` from actual master branch, link to repository is https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid.